# Filtering a Python dictionary by values of multiple keys in inner dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
transactions = {'366184179': {'start_ffe_event': '2019-12-25 19:40:47.886',
                      'tx_code': '366184179',
                      'celular': '57310XXXXXXX',
                      'AID': '121140',
                      'ffe_value': '2000.0',
                      'ITEL_type': 'ITELFlow',
                      'OfferId': '87253',
                      'partnerId': '10280',
                      'msg_ffe_event': '2019-12-25 19:40:48.858',
                      'ffe_message': 'SUCCESS response from connector',
                      'XML_event': '2019-12-25 19:40:48.858',
                      'XML_response': 'Transaction successful'},
              '366236151':{'start_ffe_event': '2019-12-26 09:01:06.594',
                           'tx_code': '366236151',
                           'celular': '573002003288',
                           'AID': '121410',
                           'ffe_value': None,
                           'ITEL_type': 'DataSmsActivationFlow',
                           'OfferId': '87461',
                           'partnerId': '10280',
                           'msg_ffe_event': None,
                           'ffe_message': None,
                           'XML_event': None,
                           'XML_response': None}
                      ...}
```

The inners keys `msg_ffe_event, ffe_message, XML_evento and XML_response` can be None

I would like to filter all keys satysfiying this condition.

I try:

```
check_keys = ['msg_ffe_event', 'ffe_message', 'XML_event', 'XML_response']
element = lambda elem: all(e is None for e in [elem[key] for key in elem.keys() if key in check_keys])
list(filter(element, transactions))
```

the element function works when I use `element(transactions[*valid_key*])` but here using the filter function produce an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-d7b33ef30b22> in <module>
      1 check_keys = ['msg_ffe_event', 'ffe_message', 'XML_event', 'XML_response']
      2 element = lambda elem: all(e is None for e in [elem[key] for key in elem.keys() if key in check_keys])
----> 3 list(filter(element, transactions))
      4 #element(transactions['366930594'])

<ipython-input-60-d7b33ef30b22> in <lambda>(elem)
      1 check_keys = ['msg_ffe_event', 'ffe_message', 'XML_event', 'XML_response']
----> 2 element = lambda elem: all(e is None for e in [elem[key] for key in elem.keys() if key in check_keys])
      3 list(filter(element, transactions))
      4 #element(transactions['366930594'])

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

My desired output is:

```
{'366236151':{'start_ffe_event': '2019-12-26 09:01:06.594',
                               'tx_code': '366236151',
                               'celular': '573002003288',
                               'AID': '121410',
                               'ffe_value': None,
                               'ITEL_type': 'DataSmsActivationFlow',
                               'OfferId': '87461',
                               'partnerId': '10280',
                               'msg_ffe_event': None,
                               'ffe_message': None,
                               'XML_event': None,
                               'XML_response': None}
                             ,...}
```

Comment: each `elem` in your lambda is simply each of the keys in the dictionary hence the error, is using lambda a requirement?

Comment: You are passing `transactions`, a dictionary, to the `filter` function, as an iterable. Iterating a dictionary gets you its keys, not the sort of key-value-pair your `element` lambda is expecting.

Comment: @aws_apprentice not lambda is  not required, I just looking for a way to filter the dict based on the inner keys

Comment: @Blorgbeard ty for your comment, the solution is:
len(list(filter(element, transactions.values())))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to achieve what you're looking for, this will match your expected output.

*All None*

```
check_keys = ['msg_ffe_event', 'ffe_message', 'XML_event', 'XML_response']

def all_keys_none(dictionary, keys):
    return all([dictionary[key] is None for key in keys])

none_keys = {key: value for key, value in transactions.items() if all_keys_none(value, check_keys)}

print(none_keys)
```

A couple of things for you to lookup.

- Looping dictionary `transaction.items()` https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary-items-method/
- Dictionary comprehension (as opposed to list comprehension). https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/

The difference between this solution and your answer is that the result will have the same dictionary structure that you started with.

Which may or may not be what you want, but is what you requested for your desired output.

Comment: ! Ty for your solution! Nice to know about dict comprehension! It works too!

Comment: No problem, both ways of doing it are fine.

Answer (score 1):

list(filter(element, transactions.values()))

tks @Blorgbeard